# How do i add weights to bones that i added after i parented the armature to the mesh?

Tags: rigging

So i added two bones to the armature after I parented the armature without those two bones to the mesh. I named them mouth lower and mouth upper, but when I select the mesh they are not in the vertex groups. How do I fix this?[image: The two highlighted bones are the ones im talking about]

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/eF4CuIX40XE

Answer (score 4):

### Find out the names of the newly-added bones

It's listed in your Properties Panel, under *Item*.

[image: Bone name]

### Create Vertex Groups on your Mesh with those names

Bones look for vertex groups with corresponding names to deform.

[image: Adding and naming a new bone]

### Paint on some weight

[image: Paint on some vertex weight]

You can do this from Weight Paint Mode, or alternatively use the Weight slider to specify a weight before clicking Assign. Always pay attention to which vertex group you have selected when weight painting.

Comment: Thank you! Was following a tutorial and they missed this important part. Since I was rigging a different gun than the one in the tutorial I could not understand why all my parts didn't move with the parent bone. This solved my issue! :)

Comment: @ChristopherSmit I'm glad you found it helpful! It's nice to see an answer I posted ages ago still having relevance for people. :-)

Comment: definitely! I'm so new to blender and come from a programming background, so still have a lot to learn. If you don't mind, maybe you can have a look at an issue I am having now? I posted a question here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/271404