# Actions seem to overlap when animating

Tags: animation, actions

I'm completely new to blender and I'm trying to learn animating and have created a simple walk animation for my rig. I then clicked on "New Action" on the action editor and created my second animation which is a shoot animation. Everything worked great and I was very proud of myself until I switched back to my walking action and realized that now when my walk animation plays, part of my shoot animation also seems to play.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? Am I misunderstanding the way this is suppose to work? I was under the impression that each action is a separate animation.

I have no idea how to fix this now and am starting to pull my hair out. I've tried googling the answer but it does not seem like anyone is having this issue besides [someone on an old reddit post from 3 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/b7b0rc/animation_actions_are_overlapping/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) who never received an answer.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can relate. How actions affect other actions can be tricky to understand at first. (It's similar to the concept of blend modes with layered images.) The best advice I can offer is to watch several video tutorials on Actions / the NLA Editor. [Here is one such tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SQdHehksJw) that I have personally found helpful. So I encourage you to start with video tutorials, and if you find out how to solve your problem, consider posting an answer to your own question. It might help someone else.

Comment: Suggest you also watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3m57yAcsi0) YT video which explains the 'nuts & bolts' of animation in Blender including the NLA editor in detail.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mentalist & @JohnEason! These videos provided some clarity and I will try this as soon as possible. :) Will provide feedback on this post as soon as I have it working.